# Asset_path duplicating prefix "assets" when using a CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm  using [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) to upload compiled assets to S3.
However, when I upgraded to rails 4, it is duplicating the prepending of "/assets" in production:

```
<%= asset_path('image.jpg') %>

Wrong: /assets//myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/image.jpg
Correct: //myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/image.jpg
```

Here is my production.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)
  config.assets.precompile += %w(static.js vendor.js static.css)
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
  config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.cache_classes = true  
  config.eager_load = true
end
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `config.assets.prefix = "/assets"`